# unit and integration test

Tags: java

I have already some integration tests for java code, I'm wondering if there is any way to detect the source and the target of each integration test, for example if we have two components A and B, when component A calls component B we should have an integration test to test these two components together, and when component B calls component A we should have another integration test, my question is from the test cases code can we decide which component is the caller and which was the callee automatically, by using tool or specific libraries.

```
public void GetPatientInfo() //testGetPatientInfo() 
{
    ArrayList<PatientInfo> patients = new ArrayList<PatientInfo>(); 
    String pid = "10"; 
    EMRService instance = new EMRService();
    instance.setPatients(patients); 
    PatientInfo p=new PatientInfo( "10", "ali", 120, 200);
    patients.add(p); 
    PatientInfo expResult = p; 
    PatientInfo result = instance.getPatientInfo(pid); 
    assertEquals(expResult, result); 
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to know which is calling? If they're the same call it shouldn't matter, and if they're different calls they should be in different tests :-) Seems pretty straightforward to me. What information are you hoping to get from knowing which is calling?

Comment: @glowcoder  Thanks for quick response,  imagine we have two classes EMRService and PatientInfo, and EMRService class implements GetPatientInfo method, in the following (integration)test case you can notice it easily that EMRService called PatientInfo, so if you decide to remove EMRService class from your system you will not need this integration test anymore(you will remove it too), because the EMRService class was the caller. otherwise if the PatientInfo was the caller then you have to update the integration test with EMRService class before remove it because PatientInfo depends on it

Comment: public void GetPatientInfo() //testGetPatientInfo()
    {

        ArrayList<PatientInfo> patients = new ArrayList<PatientInfo>();
        String pid = "10";
        EMRService instance = new EMRService();
        instance.setPatients(patients);
        PatientInfo p=new PatientInfo( "10", "ali", 120, 200);
        patients.add(p);
        PatientInfo expResult = p;
        PatientInfo result = instance.getPatientInfo(pid);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
      
   }

Answer (score 0):

You could use instanceof operator to determine the class type.

Assuming your class hierarchy looks like this:

```
interface Component { public void foo(Component bar); }
class A implements Component {}
class B implements Component {}
```

Your function could look like this:

```
public void foo(Component bar)
{
  if(bar instanceof A)
    // do one type of intergration tests
  else if(bar is instanceof B)
    // do other type of integration tests
}
```

Another possibility could be to use AOP with around-advice, or to use mocks.
If you provide more information (like example function call), I might be able to provide a better answer.

Normally you would write 2 different integration tests, one assuming that function was called with A class, another one with B class.